# Is it acceptable to reopen a closed question solely for the purpose of answering it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I'm a regular user of the [Deep Web](http://deepweb.stackexchange.com), which is currently in private beta. We as a community had reached a consensus that a certain kind of question was off-topic on the site and should be migrated, so we closed one such question. Later, a high-rep user on the site commented on the closed question:

> The question must be migrated, but I can answer, so reopen it please

Generally, I thought the rule was to not answer closed questions as this sets a bad example for future visitors to the site. I replied

> This is something that I've noticed in many of your answers. When you
>   know a question is blatantly off-topic (like this one), please don't reopen
>   it to answer it. This only encourages more off-topic questions. As for
>   this question, I agree with @JohnSmith that this question is more suited to
>   Tor.SE. As such, I've voted to leave this question closed.

to which this user replied

> I see no problem in answering a question if I know an answer. Yes, the
>   question itself seems to be more fot Tor.SE - but no migration is done
>   AFAIK, and - after all - it's a Question and Answer network, right&

I personally thought that this was not an acceptable course of action to take. Is voting to reopen a question just so you can answer it acceptable? (Also, what should I do in this situation?)

Comment: related: [Should one advise on off-topic questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/839601)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If the question is simply off topic for the site then no you should not reopen it so someone can answer. You are right - answering off topic questions give a bad precedent to future users.

If the question is a good question (important point that) and on topic elsewhere on the network then you should consider migrating it. Moderators can migrate questions to anywhere on the network, so raise a flag explaining the situation. If they agree, they can migrate it and the user can post their answer on the new site.

If the question was closed for being unclear or too broad then perhaps you should consider reopening as someone thinks they understood the question well enough to provide an answer. You should also ask them to edit the question to improve its clarity or narrow it down *before* it gets reopened to prove that it is answerable.

If the question was closed as a duplicate then you should direct the user to post their answer on the duplicate target. If they argue that their answer doesn't apply to the duplicate target, then that might indicate that the question isn't a duplicate after all. Again ask the user to edit the question to clarify the differences *before* reopening.